# Templatematching-show multiple locations

Tags: c#, opencv

Hello I am writing template-matching func in Emgu(OpenCV wrapper for C#). 
In general and I am trying to write Match Template function for 100 best matches.
I have made matchtemplate for both CPU and GPU but I can get only 1 maxLocation(only 1 possition of searched template, in source img there are about 10 of them). I have read about FloodFill with which can be deleted founded maximum and calling MinMax again will give me the 2nd maximum. But I am not able to write it(I have spent about 2 days with it so I am hopeless)

```
 string path = @"C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop";
 string imgtemplate = path+@"\TV.bmp";//smallImg
 string imgsource = path+ @"\desktop.bmp";//bigImg

 Image<Bgr, byte> source = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Imgsource); 
 Image<Bgr, byte> template = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Imgtemplate); 

 using (Image<Gray, float> result = source.MatchTemplate(template, TemplateMatchingType.SqdiffNormed))
 {

  double[] minValues, maxValues;
  Point[] minLocations, maxLocations;
  result.MinMax(out minValues, out maxValues, out minLocations, out maxLocations);
  Console.WriteLine("minVal: " + minValues[0] + " maxVal: " + maxValues[0] + " minLoc: " + minLocations[0] + " maxLoc: " + maxLocations[0]);
 }
```

I would be very thankful for help. 
Thank you !

Comment: Why are you trying to use FloodFill to do so? Why not simply set the value of the pixel located at maxLocations to 0 after you saved/used that value?

Comment: On the result from MatchTemplate I have tried to draw a filled rectangle on the area where the maxLocation is...but I wasnt able to do so...it didnt draw anything there. Problem wasnt in drawing func...I have tried on the source pic and it worked but on the result from TemplateMatch it didnt. After that I figured out that when I do: res = res.Clone(); the drawing is again possible but when I wanted to get new MaxMocation from that, it gave me some false location. After that I have tried MatchTemplate on that pic and it gave me location of the 2nd object....... After 3 days I have nothing :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with C# but here is a code written in C++ that does what you are trying to do :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat imgSrc, mask;
    Mat templatePatch, match;

    imgSrc = imread("C:/Users/be92136/Documents/Qt_Projects/Videos/grimpe1.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    templatePatch = imgSrc(Rect(50, 50, 50, 50));

    Point maxLoc;
    Size patchSize = Size(50, 50);

    matchTemplate(imgSrc, templatePatch, match, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
    mask = Mat::ones(match.size(), CV_8UC1);

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        minMaxLoc(match, NULL, NULL, NULL, &maxLoc, mask);
        Rect bestMatch = Rect(maxLoc, patchSize);
        Mat roi = mask(bestMatch);
        roi.setTo(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It uses a mask that is filled with ones at the beginning (which means the minMaxLoc function is taking the whole matches image into account). Each time a new maximum is found, the given area is removed from the mask and not considered by the next call to minMaxLoc.

Comment: I got this work also ...but please can you tell me why is needed to run matchTemplate after each mask applying ? Cant just MinMax just find new Minimum and Maximum after mask applying ?  Because on OpenCV forum somebody gave me more effective solution but written in python here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/165740/template-matching-multiple-objects/  and I dont know how to rewrite there this line: "match_locations = np.where(res<=min_thresh)" with C# code...how would you write it in C++ ?

Comment: Hello, indeed the method you just showed is more effective... But I thought you wanted  the 100 (as an absolute value) best matches, that's why I wrote the code like this :-).
in OpenCV in C++ you can simply make something like `Mat goodValues = match > threshold;`, which will create a binary matrix with 1's for pixels that were above the threshold and 0 otherwise.
Then please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242662/opencv-find-all-non-zero-coordinates-of-a-binary-mat-image to find the locations of those pixels.

Comment: You havent answered...why is it needed to run MatchTemplate multipleTimes (in your example) ? Why after deleting object from source just dont use only MinMax again ? Here is some example(but it didnt work for me either) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737420/multiple-results-in-opencvsharp3-matchtemplate

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that in my comment but you were totally right about that. I edited my code, now MatchTemplate is used only once.