# Image Matching using opencvsharp3

Tags: c#, opencv

I'm novice in OpenCVSharp3 and I've been having a look at some examples for image matching using this library.

The key to my question is that I don't know what kind of modifications the code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737420/multiple-results-in-opencvsharp3-matchtemplate/35346975#35346975) needs to compare two images that are almost 100% identical, but one of them is rotated (unlimited rotation) and sometimes slightly displaced from the source (some pixels).

The method from such question basically compare if one image is inside the other, but my project only need to compare 5 images with the same size, where two of them are the same with slightly differences.

Is valid such algorithm?

EDIT:

Here is an example of 5 images to detect the same:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be valid but:

1. if you want unlimited rotation, you have to compare your reference image with an infinite combination of rotated other image.
2. if your other image is displaced from the source you will have to generate all the possible displacement images.
3. If you combine this two technique, you will have a lot of combination.

So yes, it can be done in generating all possible different images for one image, and compare them with your reference image.

It's not very robust, what will append if you try it on images displaced with a superior amount of pixels? if a color adjustment had be done on a image? if one is in gray-scale?

I recommend you to use machine learning for this problem.
I would proceed like this:

1. make a dataset of images
2. for each images, make a data augmentation (make all rotation, displacement, noise that it is possible).
3. Use a CNN and train it to recognize each variation of an image as the same image.
4. You're done, you have an algorithm who do the job :)

Here an implementation of tensorflow for C#
https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp

For a simple implementation of MNIST CNN with python [see here](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network.ipynb)

[Here](https://brohrer.github.io/how_convolutional_neural_networks_work.html) A video that explain how CNN works (look at the feature detection and pooling operation, it can help you)